# Как следует перевести термин "audit"?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Как вы считаете, как следует переводить термин *audit*? Из базовых вариантов могу предложить:

- Аудит.
- Проверка.
- Ревизия.

Контексты:

- close votes audit
- low quality posts audit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

«проверка»: проверка голосов за закрытие, проверка некачественных сообщений.

---

*Остальные варианты*.

- «ревизия»: ревизия голосов за закрытие, ревизия некачественных сообщений.
- «аудит»: аудит голосов за закрытие, аудит некачественных сообщений.

Comment: Проверка голосов и сообщений - это review, а не audit.